# Why was I served an ice cold towel onboard?

Tags: air-travel, airlines

The other day, I was served a towel on business class, I was expecting it to be warm as it usually is. Instead, it was ice cold which was unexpected.

Why do some airlines serve ice cold towels instead of hot towels?

Comment: departure destination please

Comment: You mean, it was purposely cooled down in freezer?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some airlines (I know one at least) do serve ice cold towels for flights departing from hot countries where there is no jetway and people are transported to the plane by bus.

Usually the passengers will arrive on the plane sweaty and feeling hot and the last thing they need is a hot towel! So instead they get served an ice cold towel.

Comment: That would be very refreshing!